# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin in react native

Tags: android, react-native

```
React native android getting error /Users/jeyabaskar/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/03b7bffa42f2fb741f03fe69f60fdec1/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.1.
```

I'm using macbook m1. while run the android app i'm getting this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is an official React Native problem and they have posted a GitHub issue for resolution here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

It also includes an explanation of what happened.

It is lengthy so I'm not going to copy-paste, but basically there is a hotfix available for several versions of React Native (0.63 to 0.70), and a work-around fix if using a version that is too old to receive a hotfix.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to change your kotlin version
in `android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
      kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
     ...
    }
  ...
}
```